# Update in SQOOP Export not working

Tags: mysql, sqoop

I am using Hadoop 2.5.0 and Sqoop 1.4.5.

I am trying to update in MySQL with the following SQOOP export command:

```
sqoop export --connect "connect_string" --username "user" --password "pass" --table "table_name" --columns "A,B,created_dtm,D,E" --export-dir "export_dir" --input-null-string "" --input-null-non-string "" --input-escaped-by \\ --input-fields-terminated-by "," --input-lines-terminated-by "\\n" --update-key A --update-mode "allowinsert" -m 1;
```

A is defined as unique key in the table structure.

But I am getting the below exception and the job hangs:

```
org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlOutputFormat: Got exception in update thread: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Unknown column 'created_dtm' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1819)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1281)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlOutputFormat$AsyncSqlExecThread.run(AsyncSqlOutputFormat.java:231)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'created_dtm' in 'field list'
```

I tried the following multiple ways of specifying columns:

```
--columns A,B,created_dtm,D,E
--columns 'A','B','created_dtm','D','E'
--columns "A,B,created_dtm,D,E"
```

But none of above worked. When the above SQOOP command is executed the very first time when the table is empty then it successfully inserts all the records since I have specified --update-mode="allow-insert", but after it when I try to update the same data. The job fails every time.

Could anyone please suggest what is wrong here?

The table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists schema.`table` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `A` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  `B` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_dtm` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `C` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `E` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `D` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `u_table` (`A`),
  KEY `i_table_C` (`C`)
)
```

Comment: It got solved..There was some problem with the trigger associated with this table.